# Wix Toolset Visual Studio Extension を用いて、依存関係のあるプロジェクトのインストーラを簡単に作成する方法

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio Installer Projects を使用していたのですが、あまりに重くVSが操作不能になったり、gitでの管理が難しかったりと不満点があるので Wix を試そうとしています。

Wix本来の使い方では配置するファイルを一つずつwxsファイルに記述していくようですが、依存プロジェクトの数が多く、また、nugetで取得したファイルをすべて把握し続けることはできないので、自動的に配置ファイルを更新し続けられないかと考えました。

heatをどう組み込もうかと試行錯誤していたところ、そもそも Wix Toolset Visual Studio Extension で作成したプロジェクトの参照プロジェクトのプロパティにHarvestingに関する設定があることに気が付きました。

しかし、この Harvest: True/False をTrueに変えてみても空のインストーラが作成されるだけで、特に何かが行われたようには感じられませんでした。

この拡張機能には出力ファイルのリストを自動的に作成する機能はあるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

個人的にWix Toolset Visual Studio Extensionはあまり期待していません…。

とりあえず、[HeatProject Task](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/task_reference/heatproject.html)は`heat.exe`を呼び出すラッパーでしかないので、まずは[heat.exe](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html)を使って行いたい処理と引数を調べる必要があります。
その上で、Visual Studio上で[MSBuild プロジェクト ビルドの出力の詳細](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-dialog-box-projects-and-solutions-build-and-run?view=vs-2019)を設定して、HeatProject Taskがどこからどのようなパラメーターで呼び出されているかを確認し、意図する引数になるように`wixproj`ファイルを編集することになると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。そこまでするならbatファイルなりでスクリプト組んでビルドイベントに置いても手間はほとんど変わらないような気がします。その辺があまり期待していないというのに繋がったりしてるんでしょうか。

Comment: @v..snow そもそも回答にあげた機能はWiX toolset本体の機能で、Visual Studio Extension自身は何もしていませんので…。もちろんスクリプトでも構いませんが、wixprojなら宣言的に記述できるという利点がありますね。